# How to retrieve each column value using sql alchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using SQL Alchemy to connect to my Oracle 11g database residing in a Linux machine. I am writing a script in Python to connect to the database and retrieve values from a particular table.

The code i wrote is:

```
    from sqlalchemy import *
    def db_connection():
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('CMDC_Analyser.cfg')
    USER = config.get('DB_Connector','db.user_name' )
    PASSWORD = config.get('DB_Connector','db.password' )
    SID = config.get('DB_Connector','db.sid' )
    IP = config.get('DB_Connector','db.ip')
    PORT = config.get('DB_Connector','db.port')
    engine = create_engine('oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{ip}:{port}/{sid}'.format(user=USER, pwd=PASSWORD, ip=IP, port=PORT, sid=SID), echo=False)
    global connection
    connection = engine.connect()
    p = connection.execute("select * from ssr.bouquet")
    for columns in p:
        print columns
    connection.close()
```

The complete values from the table is printed out here. I wanted to select value from a particular column only. Hence i used the following code:

```
    for columns in p:
            print columns['BOUQUET_ID']
```

But here i am getting the following error.

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'BOUQUET_ID'"

How to fix this?

Comment: First, the obvious question - are sure you have that column in your table? One small detail I'd like to point out, your p object is a cursor, when iterating over it, you're actually iterating over rows not columns, it's just a naming detail but it's important to be well understood. Before iterating it, do a p.fetchall()

Comment: Yes. I have a column named BOUQUET_ID in the table. Here are the results from p.fetchall(). I just deleted few results due to character restrictions

        Traceback (most recent call last):
         [(24800, -1, 'Bouquet 24800', None, 0, None, None), (28898, -1, 'Bouquet 28898', None, 0, None, None)] 
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
          raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This result object is closed.")
          sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object is closed.

Comment: Please see the result for fetchall()
        <bound method ResultProxy.fetchall of <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x00000000031EE2E8>>

Comment: You are in a non-ORM mode, your query returns the result as a list of tuples, opposed to the dictionary that you expect. There would be a hack around it: col_index = p._metadata.keys.index('BOUQUET_ID')  - you do this before the loop, within the loop you'll ask for print columns[col_index]

Comment: Thanks marius. It worked. Even my code also worked when i changed from BOUQUET_ID to bouquet_id

Comment: Funny, I was going to suggest trying with lower-case, but I figured that's how you got it in your database anyway. Regardless, good that you got it working. For further development I suggest you switch to full flavor ORM.